# How to implement timeouts in a multithreaded program?

Tags: python, multithreading, timeout

I have this sample code:

```
import threading
from Queue import Queue
q = Queue(maxsize=0)
def work(q):
    #do a job
for line in file_of_100_line:
    q.put(line)
nbThreads = 2
for i in range(nbThreads):
    t = threading.Thread(target=work, args=(q))
    t.setDaemon(True)
    t.start()
```

and I wanted to make a thread end if the threads takes more than "x" seconds to execute. How could I do that with multithreading? Thanks

Comment: `time.time()` and `time.clock()` both should work in a multi-thread program. So you could use them just like in a regular program. BTW, the indentation of your code is messed-up.

Comment: I'm trying it out, but the indentation of my code is not messed-up.

Comment: Maybe it just looks that way because you left statements out...